# How can I sort sentences based on dates contained in them using python

Tags: python, regex, sorting, date

I have a few paragraphs of customer data. Each paragraph starts with dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss. I need to sort these paragraphs based on the date time stamp contained in them

I need to use python for this. I have tried regex on python but didn't get the output

Code:

```
*sep2 = '([0-3]?\d)[- \/.](0\d|1[0-2])[- \/.]((19|20)\d\d) ([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)'  
text2 = text1.split(sep2)  
print(text2)*
```

Input contains paragraphs which are unseparated by date. example of one paragraph:

```
21.01.2017 09:05:56 abcsdfasklfvd 02.01.2017 09:05:56 afgdsfggv
```

Expected output:

```
text2[0] = 21.01.2017 09:05:56 abcsdfasklfvd  
text2[1] = 02.01.2017 09:05:56 afgdsfggv
```

then I want to apply some sorting function based on ascending date which would give

expected output:

```
sorted[0] = 02.01.2017 09:05:56 afgdsfggv  
sorted[1] = 21.01.2017 09:05:56 abcsdfasklfvd
```

Comment: This is why it's preferabble to have the dates in the format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`. You would just `sorted(text2)` and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime 

text = ["21.01.2017 09:05:56 abcsdfasklfvd", "02.01.2017 09:05:56 afgdsfggv"]
sorted(text, key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s[0:19], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

---

If the pattern `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss` does not appear inside paragraphs then you can use

```
text1 = "21.01.2017 09:05:56 abcsdfasklfvd 02.01.2017 09:05:56 afgdsfggv"

text = list()
for d, t in zip(*[iter(re.split(r'(\d+.\d+.\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)', text1)[1:])]*2):
    text.append(d + t)

sorted(text, key=lambda s: datetime.strptime(s[0:19], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

---

```
def extract(s):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(s, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')        
    except (ValueError):
        return datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
sorted(text, key=lambda s: extract(s[0:19]))
```

Comment: hi, my data is large. Unfortunately manual serparation of the paragraphs into different elements of an array is not possible

Comment: @SakshiJajodia Updated the answer. Please update your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped solve my problem